# reproduce multiple apache rewrites in IIS 8 with URL Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8

My previous web server ran apache with rewrites in each site's .conf file. I wouldn't even consider myself an intermediate rewrite user so this may not be ideal. I'm trying to reproduce this:

```
# except for requests for URL-path /abc/abc_system<whatever> 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/abc/abc_system|/abc/themes|/abc/admin.php)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.)*abctest\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/abc/(.*)$ /abc/index.php/abc/$1 [L]
# one
RewriteRule ^/one/(.*)$ /one/index.php/one/$1 [L]
# two
RewriteRule ^/two/(.*)$ /two/index.php/two/$1 [L]
# three
RewriteRule ^/three/(.*)$ /three/index.php/three/$1 [L]
```

within IIS 8 using URL Rewrite.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="abc ee" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="^abc/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(/abc/abc_system|/abc/themes|/abc/admin.php)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^.]+\.)*abctest\.example\.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/abc/index.php/abc/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="abc one" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="^/one/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/one/index.php/one/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The first rule is working but the second one ("abc one") isn't, so I haven't even bothered adding the rules for "two" and "three" yet.

Basically the urls look something like this:

example.com/abc -> example.com/abc/index.php/abc (working)

example.com/one -> example.com/one/index.php/one

example.com/two -> example.com/two/index.php/two

example.com/three -> example.com/three/index.php/three

What am I doing wrong that the second rule isn't working?
Once that's fixed, is repeating it the best way to go about it or is there a more efficient way to condense them down?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "OR" to catch the two/three cases and will be faster, I tested the following rule and it worked fine:

```
            <rule name="RewriteOneTwoThree" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(one|two|three)/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/index.php/{R:1}/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
```